# how to get inbox folder instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

If I want to know how many items in inbox, I use TotalCount Property, but how do I get inbox folder first? If I use FindFoldersResults findFolders=service.FindFolders() method, what is the parentfolder name for inbox? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
var folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out, hope the answer could help others.

SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "inbox");
        FindFoldersResults f = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot,searchFilter,new FolderView(10));

The f is a folder array that conclude only one folder which is "Inbox" folder

Comment: This won't work for non-english mailboxes because the name of the inbox folder is localized. It's Posteingang for example in german. See my other answer for the correct way to solve this issue.